# Cannot connect to SQL Server as a member of AD group

Tags: sql-server, authentication, active-directory, database-connection

I am facing an error to connect to SQL Server as a member of a new AD group. Could anyone advise below?

I am a member of an AD group and this AD group has DB owner access in the instance and database level on SQL Server through Windows Authentication.

When I tried to connect to the database sever, the I faced the below error message:

> "Cannot connect to database_server_instance_name. 
>   Login failed for user 'domain_name\my_user_id' (Microsoft SQL Server Error, Error: 18456)"

I double checked the permission settings for the AD group and it is added as "Groups".

This AD group has a few other users and same issue is observed by everyone in the group.

I am planning to request our security team to check the AD group settings. May I know what would be possibly missing with the AD group?

Comment: See if someone else you know in that AD group can login.  That will tell you if it's a group issue or your specific user.  Also you might have to wait a while or log off and back on for AD to refresh (if this was literally just completed)

Comment: @AaronDietz Thank you for your response. There are a few more users in the same AD group and everyone cannot login. We have been facing this issue for over a day.

Comment: I would go to your security team with exactly that - "The login isn't working for *anyone* and here is the error message".  I guess they haven't created the AD user in SQL Server, or they made a typo etc.  Here is a walkthrough as an FYI, but ultimately you're providing them with more information than should be expected of you already :) https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/how-do-i-assign-an-entire-active-directory-group-security-access-in-sql-server-2

Comment: What do you mean by "checked the permission settings for the AD group and it is added as Groups"? Try `CREATE LOGIN 'YourDomain\Group`;`. The SQL Server error log may have additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is resolved. The AD group was set to Domain local only. Since the database server belongs to another domain, that is why we were facing this error.
We changed to Universal and it is working now for all users in the AD group.

Thank you everyone to help me out to figure out this problem.